# how to have comunication Service-UI when services has attribute Process colon(:)

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have an service which work fine, but when the app crashes the service is stopped, I want the service continue running then

in manifest I have this

```
<service
    android:name=".Services.SSubProcesoGps"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    />
```

but if I update the manifest to

```
<service
    android:name=".Services.SSubProcesoGps"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":foo"
    />
```

the service is not working well
What the service does?
save the gps coordinates 
send the gps coordinates
using sendbroadcast update the UI
but then the manifest is updated the UI is not updated
(I dont know if the other things or gps are working because when colon is added I cant debug the service)

```
public class SSubProcesoGps extends RoboService implements LocationListener{

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    double latitud = 0;
    double longitud = 0;
    public static int hacambiado = 0;
    public static boolean isRunning = false;
    double contadorCronometro = 0;
    long iniciocontador=0;

    public static boolean guardarDatos = false;
    boolean gpsIniciado = false;
    Notification notification = null;

    long startTime;
    Posicion mPosicion = null;
    //Location mLocation=null;
    Posicion mPosicionAnterior = null;
    //Location mLocationAnterior=null;
    boolean crearNuevaPosicion = false;

    public static final String response_result = "myresult";
    public static final String response_message = "mymessaje";

    public static final String response_messageGps = "mymessajeGps";
    public static final String response_messageEncenderGps = "mymessajeEncenderGps";


    private Recorrido recorrido = null;
    @Inject
    RecorridoSync recorridoSync;
    @Inject
    PosicionesSync posicionesSync;

    @Inject
    ConnectionStatusSync connectionStatusSync;


    public static Thread threadCronometro;
    static Thread ThreadTiempoLanzar;
    static Thread ThreadCoordenadas;



    @Inject
    DataManagerSubProcesoGps mDataManager;

    int Maxsegundos = 30; // un hilo/thread ejecutara(creará) cada N segundos
    // otro hilo que envia informacion (recorridos y posiciones)
    int segundos = 0;//este es el contador del anterior si es igual a MaxSegundos vuelve a 0
    int tiempoGps = 0;//el tiempo en cada cuantos segundos guardará datos
    int tiempoGpsListener=2; // cada cuanto tiempo el listener intentará obtener informacion
    boolean monitorearVariacionVelocidad=false;
    float velocidadMinimaVariacion=0;
    int distanciaMonitoreo=0;

    boolean MonitorearXTiempo=false;
    boolean mEsPrimero=true;

    Location currentLoc=null;
    Location oldLoc=null;

    boolean ListenerRegistrados=false;

    private  void getConfiguracion()
    {
        ParametrosRecorrido parametrosRecorrido=mDataManager.getParametrosRecorrido();
        Maxsegundos= tiempoGps=parametrosRecorrido.getIntervaloTiempoMonitoreo();
        monitorearVariacionVelocidad= parametrosRecorrido.getMonitorearVariacionVelocidad();
        velocidadMinimaVariacion= parametrosRecorrido.getVelocidadMinimaVariacion();
        distanciaMonitoreo=parametrosRecorrido.getIntervaloDistanciaMonitoreo();
        if(distanciaMonitoreo>0) {
            MonitorearXTiempo=false;

        }else{
            distanciaMonitoreo = 0;
            MonitorearXTiempo=true;

        }



    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

LocationListener(loc,false);
    }

    void LocationListener(Location loc, boolean esSegundoListener)
    {
        AvisarGpsEstaFuncionando(true,false);

        if (guardarDatos) {

            oldLoc=currentLoc;
            currentLoc=loc;
            inicializaPosicion(loc,esSegundoListener);

        } else {
            oldLoc=currentLoc=null;
            mPosicionAnterior = mPosicion = null;

        }

    }

    float calculaAceleracion()
    {

        if(oldLoc!=null && currentLoc!=null)
        {
            if(currentLoc.hasSpeed() && oldLoc.hasSpeed())
            {
                //formula es velocidad actual -velocidad anterior / el intervalo de tiempo
                // (tiempo final - tiempo anterior)

               float aceleracion=  (currentLoc.getSpeed()-oldLoc.getSpeed())/((currentLoc.getTime()-oldLoc.getTime())/1000);
                String texto="("+String.valueOf(currentLoc.getSpeed())+"\n"
                    +"-"+String.valueOf(oldLoc.getSpeed())+")\n"
                        +"/(("+String.valueOf(currentLoc.getTime())+"\n"
                        +"-"+oldLoc.getTime()+")/1000)";
                MensajeAceleracion(aceleracion,texto);
                return  aceleracion;


            }
        }
        return  0;
    }
    void inicializaPosicion(Location loc, boolean esSegundoListener) {

        if (mPosicion == null || crearNuevaPosicion && loc != null) {
            mPosicion = new Posicion();
            crearNuevaPosicion = false;
        }


        if (loc != null) {
            float Aceleracion = calculaAceleracion();
            mPosicion.setEstatusEnviado(EstatusEnviado.Sin_Enviar.getValue());
            if (loc.hasAccuracy())
                mPosicion.setPrecision(loc.getAccuracy());
            if (loc.hasSpeed()) {
                mPosicion.setVelocidad(loc.getSpeed());
                //     velocidadfinal= loc.getSpeed();
            }
            if (loc.hasBearing())
                mPosicion.setOrientacion(loc.getBearing());
            if (loc.hasAltitude())
                mPosicion.setAltitud(loc.getAltitude());
            mPosicion.setFechaLectura(longtoDate(loc.getTime()));

            mPosicion.setLatitud(loc.getLatitude());
            mPosicion.setLongitud(loc.getLongitude());
            mPosicion.setAceleracion(Aceleracion);

            float AceleracionPositiva= (Aceleracion>0)? Aceleracion: (Aceleracion*(-1));
            //guarda cuando se detecta una aceleracion mayor o igual configurada por el usuario
            if (monitorearVariacionVelocidad && AceleracionPositiva >= velocidadMinimaVariacion) {
                GuardarenHilo();
            }

            //significa que guardara información cuando esté configurado que guarde por tiempo
            if ( !esSegundoListener && guardarDatos && (!MonitorearXTiempo ) || mEsPrimero) {
                if (mPosicion != null && mPosicion.getFechaLectura() != null) {

                GuardarenHilo();
                    mEsPrimero=false;

                }


            }


        }
    }

    void GuardarenHilo()
    {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                guardarDatos(mPosicion);
                mPosicionAnterior = mPosicion;
                crearNuevaPosicion = true;

            }
        });

        hilo.start();
    }

    void guardarDatos(Posicion posicion1) {

        if (posicion1 != null  && posicion1.getFechaLectura()!=null) {

            Date date = posicion1.getFechaLectura();
            iniciarRecorrido(date);
            CreaPosicionGps(posicion1);
        }

    }

    private Date longtoDate(long longDate) {

        // See notes below
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date(longDate);
        String formatted = format.format(date);
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        String xx = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        String xx = s;

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        String xx = s;


        AvisarGpsEstaFuncionando(false,false);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        isRunning = true;
        mEsPrimero=true;
        getConfiguracion();
        LanzarThreadIntervaloTiempo();



        int value = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if (guardarDatos) {
            iniciarCronometro();
            IniciarForeGround();
            //RecorridosIdBackground();


        } else {
            currentLoc=oldLoc=null;
            recorrido = null;
            IniciarGps();
            AvisarGpsEstaFuncionando(false,true);
            detenerCronometro();
            detenerForeground();
            //detenerSaveCoordenadas();
        }
        //esta fuera por que el proceso inicia cuando se entra al servicio
        //pero no guarda nada hasa que tenga "guardarDatos" como true
        if(MonitorearXTiempo)
        SaveGpsCoordenadas();

        return START_STICKY;
        //return value;

    }

    void gpsEnable() {
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = false;//actualmente solo gps

    }

    void IniciarForeGround() {
        if (guardarDatos) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            if (notification == null)
                notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)  // the status icon
                        .setTicker("hola muy myintentservice")  // the status text
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())  // the time stamp
                        .setContentTitle("content title")  // the label of the entry
                        .setContentText("content teext")  // the contents of the entry
                        .setContentIntent(pendIntent)  // The intent to send when the entry is clicked
                        .build();

            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
    }

    void detenerForeground() {
        if (notification != null)
            stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        isRunning = false;

    }

    public void AvisarGpsEstaFuncionando(boolean valor, boolean fake) {


        Intent intent1 = new Intent("mx.twothePoint.app.gps");
        intent1.putExtra(response_messageGps, valor);
        intent1.putExtra("isFake", fake);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);

    }



    public void MensajeAceleracion(float valor,String texto) {


/*        Intent intent1 = new Intent("mx.twothePoint.app.aceleracion");
        intent1.putExtra("x", valor);
        intent1.putExtra("y", texto);

        sendBroadcast(intent1);
*/
    }





    public void sendResult() {


        Intent intent1 = new Intent("mx.twothePoint.app.Cronometro");
        intent1.putExtra(response_message, contadorCronometro);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;
        startService(new Intent(this, SSubProcesoGps.class));

    }

    void iniciarRecorrido(Date fechaInicio) {
        if (recorrido == null)
            recorrido = mDataManager.creaRecorrido(fechaInicio);

    }

    void CreaPosicionGps(Posicion posicion1) {
        if (recorrido != null)
            mPosicion = mDataManager.creaPosicion(recorrido, posicion1.getAceleracion()
                    , posicion1.getAltitud(), posicion1.getFechaLectura(), posicion1.getLatitud()
                    , posicion1.getLongitud(), posicion1.getOrientacion(), posicion1.getVelocidad()
                    , posicion1.getPrecision());

    }

    void iniciarCronometro() {
        contadorCronometro =0;
        iniciocontador=new Date().getTime(); //obtengo el inicio
        if(threadCronometro==null)
        threadCronometro = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    sendResult();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }

                    contadorCronometro = (new Date().getTime()-iniciocontador)/1000;

                    //contadorCronometro++;
                }
            }
        });
        //if(!threadCronometro.isAlive())
            if(threadCronometro.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        threadCronometro.start();

    }

    void SaveGpsCoordenadas() {

        if (ThreadCoordenadas == null)
            ThreadCoordenadas = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        try {
                            if (guardarDatos) {
                                if (mPosicion != null && mPosicion.getFechaLectura()!=null) {
                                    guardarDatos(mPosicion);
                                    mPosicionAnterior = mPosicion;
                                    crearNuevaPosicion = true;

                                    Thread.sleep(1000 * tiempoGps);
                                }


                            } else {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        //if (!ThreadCoordenadas.isAlive())
            if(ThreadCoordenadas.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            ThreadCoordenadas.start();
    }

    void RecorridosIdBackground() {
       /*Intent Intent = new Intent(this, SSubProcesoSendRecorrido.class);
        startService(Intent);
*/

        Thread EnviarCoordenadasHilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ObtenerRecorridoId();
                EnviarPosiciones();
            }
        });

        Command command = new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {

            }
        };
        connectionStatusSync.CheckConnection(EnviarCoordenadasHilo,command);


    }


    void LanzarThreadIntervaloTiempo() {

        if (ThreadTiempoLanzar == null)
            ThreadTiempoLanzar = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (segundos == Maxsegundos) {
                            segundos = 0;
                            RecorridosIdBackground();

                        }
                        segundos++;
                    }
                }
            });

        //if (!ThreadTiempoLanzar.isAlive())
            if(ThreadTiempoLanzar.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            ThreadTiempoLanzar.start();


    }

    /**
     * Obteiene el recorridoId para todos los recorridos que estan guardados en la BD interna
     */
    void ObtenerRecorridoId() {
        //solo consigo los recorridos que tienen gps (obviamente sin enviar)
        //pues no tiene caso conseguir un recorrido que no tiene coordenadas gps
        List<Recorrido> recorridos = mDataManager.getRecorridosSinIdSinEnviar();
        if(recorridos.size()>0) {
            mDataManager.UpdateEnviandoList(recorridos);
            int uno=1;
            //recorridos.forEach(x->recorridoSync.getRecorridoId(x));
            for (int i = 0; i < recorridos.size(); i++) {
                recorridoSync.getRecorridoId(recorridos.get(i));
            }
        }


    }

    void EnviarPosiciones() {
        //consigos los recorridos que tienen gps sin enviar
        List<Recorrido> recorridos = mDataManager.getRecorridosConGpsSinEnviar();
        List<Posicion> allPosicion = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < recorridos.size(); i++) {
            recorridos.get(i).resetPosiciones();
            allPosicion.addAll( mDataManager.getPosicionesSinEnviarById(recorridos.get(i).getId()));
        }
        //quiere decir que solo esta el ultimo recorridoID
        //por que los demás ya los ha enviado
        if(recorridos.size()==1)
        {
            mDataManager.EliminaRecorridosFinalizados(recorridos.get(0).getId());
        }

        //elimino los que estan marcados como enviado (aunque ya deben estar eliminados)
       // mDataManager.removeEnviandoListPosiciones(allPosicion);
        //actulizo como "enviando"
        mDataManager.UpdateEnviandoListPosiciones(allPosicion);

//despues de actualizar el estatus empiezo a enviar los detalles de cada recorrido
        for (int i = 0; i < recorridos.size(); i++) {
            //este select esta obteniendo los que tienen el estatus sin_enviar
            List<Posicion> posicions = mDataManager.getPosicionesSinEnviarByIdRecorridoinMemory(recorridos.get(i).getId(), allPosicion);

            if (posicions.size() > 0) {
                posicionesSync.sendPosiciones(posicions, recorridos.get(i).getRecorridoId());
            }
        }

    }



    void detenerCronometro() {

        if (threadCronometro != null && threadCronometro.isAlive())
            threadCronometro.interrupt();
    }


    void IniciarGps() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            gpsEnable();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            //si los listener aun no estan registrados entonces los regitro
            if(!ListenerRegistrados)
            if(MonitorearXTiempo) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (tiempoGpsListener * 1000), 0, this);
            }else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, distanciaMonitoreo, this);

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (tiempoGpsListener * 1000), 0, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        LocationListener(location,true);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                    }
                });

            }
            ListenerRegistrados=true;



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Check LogCat for any messages related to failures in the broadcasts. I have not played much with having a service in a separate process, but it might be that you need to have the `BroadcastReceiver` (or receivers) be exported.

Comment: I am using broadcastreceiver and this work fine when I remove android:process=":foo" but it not working when the line is not removed

Comment: Yes, I understand that. When you have `android:process=":foo"` in place, check LogCat for any messages related to failures in the broadcasts.

Comment: logCat is empty related to broadcast, unique message is about a thread

Comment: But i have seen when I add <code>android:process=":foo"</code> I cant save the data in database (using GreenDao)